# Connecting IntelliJ to weblogic server

Tags: java, intellij-idea, weblogic

I have a server that it has weblogic on its own. I develop my program with intelliJ. Can I connect intelliJ to the weblogic server and just run and deploy the project from intelliJ (just like when we use Tomcat application server on our local and start/stop that with intelliJ)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You indeed can. You can create a `Run/Debug configuration` for WebLogic same way as for Tomcat, but you might see it as an option only after you click `N items more (irrelevant)`, which is at the very bottom of the list.

Also, this is supported only in Ultimate edition. If you're using community edition, you can't do that from the IDE.

The process of configuration is also described in [Intellij IDEA's guides](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-weblogic-server.html)